# Tokenizing a file with a generator

Tags: python, parsing, file, generator

I'm parsing (specifically tokenizing) a file, line-by-line. I've a method tokenize, that takes a string (one line of code, it can't take the whole file at once), breaks it into parts, and returns a generator that yields those parts until it reaches the end of line. This is all given. I implemented some methods, that will give me all of the file parts (i.e. feeding each line to tokenize, and sending each line parts). Here's what I did, I feel it's very cumbersome and ugly.

```
class tokenizer:
    def __init__(self,read_file):
        self.file = read_file
        self.line = self.file.readline()
        self.gen = tokenize(self.line)
        self.token = Token("","","","")

    def advance(self):
        return self.token

    def hasMoreTokens(self):
        try:
            self.token = self.gen.__next__()
        except StopIteration:
            self.line = self.file.readline()
            if self.line == '':
                return False
            self.gen = tokenize(self.line)
            self.token = self.gen.__next__()
        return True

with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as file:
    tknzr = tokenizer(file)
    while tknzr.hasMoreTokens():
        print(tknzr.advance())
```

Could you advise me on how to make a more logical and sensible implementation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python already constructs a generator when you loop over a file object with a for loop. So you could simplify your code to:

```
with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for token in tokenize(line):
            print(token)
```

Note that I renamed the `file` variable to `f`, to avoid shadowing the built-in `file`.

---

If you really need to implement a class, you should implement the [iterator protocol](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-3rd/9781449357337/ch04s04.html), allowing Python to iterate over your object. First, let me define a dummy `tokenize` function for testing purposes:

```
def tokenize(line):
    return line.split()
```

Then, let's define the class. Note that I renamed it in `PascalCase`, to adhere to Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

It has two important methods, first the `__iter__` method, which just returns `self`. This just tells Python that this class is the actual iterator which it can iterate over. It is important for if you nest `iter` calls, namely `iter(iter(tokenizer)) == iter(tokenizer)`.

The second important method is the `__next__` method, which, just like the name suggests, tells Python how to get the next element from the iterator. It is similar to your implementation, only I use the iterator interface of the file. This method is called a second time if we got to a new line. It will stop at the end of the file, because then the unguarded `next(self.file_it)` will `raise StopIteration`, which the `for` loop will catch and stop iterating.

Note that since we call `iter` on the output of the `tokenize` function, it is enough for `tokenize` to return an iterable (this can be a `list`, like  here, but it can also be an iterator itself).

```
class Tokenizer:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.file_it = iter(f)
        self.token_it = None

    def __next__(self):
        if self.token_it is None:
            self.token_it = iter(tokenize(next(self.file_it)))
        try:
            return next(self.token_it)
        except StopIteration:
            self.token_it = None
            return next(self)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

if __name__ == "__main__":        
    with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as f:
        for token in Tokenizer(f):
            print(token)
```

I also added a [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard around your code running the tokenizer to allow importing this class from other scripts.

---

Normally I would expect the `tokenize` function to be a method of the `Tokenizer`. Either directly defined:

```
class Tokenizer:
    ...
    def tokenize(self, line):
        return line.split()
    ...
```

Or, using the strategy pattern, plugged in at creation time:

```
def tokenize(line):
    return line.split()

class Tokenizer:
    def __init__(self, f, tokenize):
        self.f_it = iter(f)
        self.tokenize = tokenize
        self.token_it = None
    ...
```

Or, using inheritance:

```
class Tokenizer:
    ...
    def tokenize(self, line):
        raise NotImplementedError


class SplitTokenizer(Tokenizer):
    def tokenize(self, line):
        return line.split()
```

Comment: Is there any documentation for `file`? I've been looking for it for quite some time now.

Comment: You can type `help(file)` in an interactive Python session. But I just discovered that `file` does not exist as a built-in anymore in Python 3. So you need to open a Python2 console for that.